# How to return a value using constructor in c#?

Tags: .net, constructor

I follow a convention that I won't use any print statements in classes, but I have done a parameter validation in a constructor. Please tell me how to return that validation which I've done in the constructor to the Main function.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The constructor does return a value - the type being constructed...

A constructor is not supposed to return any other type of value.

When you validate in a constructor, you should throw *exceptions* if the passed in values are invalid.

```
public class MyType
{
    public MyType(int toValidate)
    {
      if (toValidate < 0)
      {
        throw new ArgumentException("toValidate should be positive!");
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: oohh, I wish I could up vote thousand times. It's so tiresome with that permissive validation style that is spreading like cancer.

Comment: @jgauffin - What style do you mean?

Comment: For instance using DataAnnotation attributes on your domain/business models. i.e. allowing objects to have invalid information and relying on the calling code to make sure that everything is validated and correct. you know.. violating encapsulation.

Comment: @jgauffin - I see. Annotating but not checking that the invariants are actually held.

Answer (score 5):

Constructors do not have a return type, but you can pass values by reference using the `ref` keyword. It would be better to throw an exception from the constructor to indicate a validation failure.

```
public class YourClass
{
    public YourClass(ref string msg)
    {
         msg = "your message";
    }

}    

public void CallingMethod()
{
    string msg = string.Empty;
    YourClass c = new YourClass(ref msg);       
}
```

Comment: That you _can_ doesn't mean you _should_.

Answer (score 2):

Make a Constructor with Out parameter and send your return value via same.

```
public class ClassA
{
    public ClassA(out bool success)
    {
        success = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your class is too fragile if it comes to this.

Answer (score 1):

A constructor returns the type being instantiated, and, if necessary, can throw an exception. Perhaps a better solution would be to add a static method to *try* creating an instance of your class:

```
public static bool TryCreatingMyClass(out MyClass result, out string message)
{
    // Set the value of result and message, return true if success, false if failure
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think my approach might be useful also. Need to add public property to constructor, then you can access this property form other class, as in below example.

```
// constructor
public class DoSomeStuffForm : Form
{
    private int _value;

    public DoSomeStuffForm
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // do some calculations
        int calcResult = 60;
        _value = calcResult;
    }

    // add public property
    public int ValueToReturn
    {
        get 
        {
            return _value;
        }
    }
}

// call constructor from other class
public statc void ShowDoSomeStuffForm()
{
    int resultFromConstructor;

    DoSomeStuffForm newForm = new DoSomeStuffForm()
    newForm.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
    newForm.ShowDialog();

    // now you can access value from constructor
    resultFromConstructor = newForm.ValueToReturn;

    newForm.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When a constructor receives an invalid argument, it's common to throw an exception. You can then catch this exception and parse the data it contains.

```
try
{
    int input = -1;
    var myClass = new MyClass(input);
}
catch (ArgumentException ex)
{
    // Validation failed.
}
```