# Populating an object at initialization using its constructor and an object returned from a serialized stream

Tags: c#, .net

I'm writing a wrapper for a static API (Jenkins CI) and I'm trying to make my life easier when dealing with serialized objects I receive from a .Net System.Net.WebResponse by writing a function into the object class to perform the WebRequest and get the object. This works fine until I want to initialize an instance of the object in its constructor. Here's what I mean:

```
[DataContract]
public class ApiData
{
    public ApiData(string url)
    {
       // Assignment of object instance here 
    }

    [DataMember]
    public List<object> actions { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string description { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    ...
    [DataMember]
    public List<object> upstreamProjects { get; set; }

    public ApiData get_job_data(string url)
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        var response = request.GetResponse();

        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ApiData));
        return (ApiData)serializer.ReadObject(response.GetResponseStream());
    }
}
```

Then when I instantiate the object as below, I'll have a fully initialized object in only one line.

```
        string job_url = "http://apihost.com/dir/job/api/json";
        ApiData job_data = new ApiData(job_url);
```

I know that I can just assign each property from the returned, serialized object to each property of the instance, but the list of properties is quite long, and this work will be repeated for several more classes. Is what I want to do possible? Am I missing something basic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after thinking about it, I'm basically trying to [return a value to a new object using the object's constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497626/how-to-return-a-value-using-constructor-in-c), which is just silly. I also was trying to save *only one line* by reducing

```
ApiData job_data = new ApiData();
job_data = ApiData.get_job_data(job_url);
// get_job_data() only exists really to save time writing out the webrequest,
// so I included it as a class method
```

to

```
ApiData job_data = new ApiData(job_url);
```

This is trivial. When I'll be calling this, I'll most likely care only about one or two values, so I'm not saving a lot of time. This is my first question on StackOverflow, so I'll try to think a little more before asking. Thanks, Yuval Itzchakov, for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, what you need is a generic deserialize method. What You can do is write a `Generic` method with a `T` parameter which you can call on all the objects you want to deserialize.

It might look like this:

```
public static class RequestDeserializer
{
    public static T SendRequestAndDeserialize<T>(string url) where T : new()
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        var response = request.GetResponse();

        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        return (T)serializer.ReadObject(response.GetResponseStream());
    }
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
var myDeserializedObject = RequestDeserializer.SendRequestAndDeserialize<ApiData>(url);
```

Of course, this sample does not include `Exception` handling which has to be taken into consideration, and of course the architecture of your system, this might be more suitable in the `Data Access Layer` of your code.

I would suggest looking into [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) as it makes dealing with JSON data much easier :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I actually have no problem serializing the response. I was hoping to put object get and serialize code into a constructor to initialize an instance of the object at declaration of a new ApiData(url)...wait a minute. I'm being very stupid. See answer.

Comment: Sorry - disregard the last part of my previous comment. My answer is what I ended up doing.